# Is access to a static instance of a c# class with only public getters, thread safe?

Tags: c#

e.g.: say I have a class "Car", with only public getters (which don't have any side effects):

```
public enum CarType
{
    Hatch,
    SUV,
}

public class Car
{
    public Car(CarType carType, string model, bool isElectric)
    {
        CarType = carType;
        Model = model;
        IsElectric = isElectric;
    }

    public CarType CarType { get; private set; }
    public string Model { get; private set; }
    public bool IsElectric { get; private set; }
}
```

Now a static instance of the Car class is created in some other C# class, like this:

```
protected static readonly Car _defaultCar = new Car(CarType.SUV, "123", true);
```

Is it safe to use _defaultCar from multiple threads ?

Comment: This depends on how the default_Car is being used and why you need this..

Comment: As currently defined, yes it is safe.

Comment: The reason that something would not be thread-safe is pretty much only ever going to be that a read operation may occur while an incomplete write operation is in progress. If there are no write operations, there can be no issues between threads.

Comment: It is not obvious from the C# syntax, but it takes the static constructor of "other C# class" to get that field initialized.  The C# compiler auto-generates/modifies that constructor as necessary.  So yes, the CLR spec promises that static constructors are thread-safe and get executed before any code accesses the static field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the object is immutable, it is perfectly safe to access from multiple threads. This is true in general, regardless if the object is static or not. Private setters are not sufficient in it self, since there could be methods that mutate the properties.

Note that you should remove the private setter for immutable objects, creating get-only properties. That better signals that the type is immutable. In some cases you can also use a readonly struct to guarantee immutability.

Also keep in mind what objects you expose. Bool, string, and enums are all immutable, but if you exposed say a list, you risk the list being mutated, and lists are *not* thread safe.